# I can't get Django to INNER JOIN properly :(

Tags: django, vue.js, inner-join

Despite having looked everywhere for similar issues I still cannot make the query working using INNER JOIN with the Django ORM... Sorry if this might sound stupid, but this is my first time with Django on a project and especially the ORM.

I have an Articles table with a Users table (named Fellows in my case), the Articles table has it's foreign key on author and references the user_id in Fellows table.

```
class Fellow(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # ID
    user_id = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(db_column='User_ID', unique=True)  # Global User ID.
    nickname = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=64, db_collation='utf8mb4_general_ci')  # Display Name
    user_password = models.CharField(db_column='User_Password', max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)  # Passwd
    gold = models.IntegerField(db_column='Gold')  # Credits
    faction = models.ForeignKey('Faction', models.RESTRICT, db_column='Faction', default=1)  # ID Faction

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Fellows'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nickname # Test.

class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # ID
    author = models.ForeignKey('Fellow', models.CASCADE, db_column='ID_User', default=1)  # Global User ID
    title = models.CharField(db_column='Title', max_length=32)  # Title
    content = models.TextField(db_column='Content')  # Content
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Posted')  # Date Posted
    source = models.CharField(db_column='Source', max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) # Source picture url of the article.

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Articles'
```

I tried to get the display name of the related author that posted the article without success.

This is my views.py:

```
from .models import Article

def index(request):
    """
        And then Vue.JS will take care of the rest.
    """
    # articles = Article.objects.order_by('-posted')[:5] # Returns everything inside Articles table but nothing inside Fellows table.
    
    # articles = Article.objects.select_related() # No Result.
    
    # Still can't get display_name in index.html with this one.
    articles = Article.objects.raw('SELECT Fellows.Name AS Display_Name, Articles.ID, Articles.Title, Articles.Content, Articles.Posted, Articles.Source FROM Articles INNER JOIN Fellows ON Fellows.User_ID = Articles.ID_User ORDER BY Articles.ID DESC LIMIT 5;')

    data = {
        'articles': articles,
    }

    return render(request, 'home/index.html', data)
```

The raw request returns everything fine only with sql interpreter, so there is two options:

1. Django won't perform the INNER JOIN.
2. I didn't figured out how to read the Display_Name in the template (index.html).

This is how I retrieve the data using VueJS (even with the raw query I can't get the display_name, it's empty).

```
<script>
    const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            articles: [
                {% for article in articles %}
                {
                    title: '{{ article.title }}',
                    content: '{{ article.content | linebreaksbr }}',
                    source: "{% static 'home/img/' %}" + '{{article.source}}',
                    display_name: '{{article.display_name}}', // Maybe this is not how to retrieve the display_name?
                },
                {% endfor %}
            ],
        },
    });

    // Components.
    ArticleList = Vue.component('article-list', {
        data: function () { return { articles: store.state.articles } },
        template: '#article-list-template',
    });

    ArticleItem = Vue.component('article-item', {
        delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
        props: ['id', 'title', 'content', 'source', 'display_name'],
        template: '#article-item-template',
    });
...
</script>
```

if someone could help me with this I would appreciate immensely! TT

Comment: `Article.objects.select_related('author').all()` and `{{ article.author.nickname }}` in the template should work. You have to reference field names, not database column names.

Comment: Than you for your reply,
I tried your suggested method however it returns an empty list.
I have tested with another app using other models with foreign keys, but with a simple template this time (no vuejs), and it worked as expected. I will try with a dummy app with the same tables this time to find out where the problem is ! x_x

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved,

I had to change the foreign key constraint Articles.ID_User which now leads to Fellows.ID.

Previously the constraint led to Fellows.User_ID.

I can finally use:

```
articles = Article.objects.select_related('author').order_by('-posted')[:5]
```

And indeed finally accessing it in the front by *article.author*, simple as that.

Yet I still don't really understand why the raw sql query (using the mysql interpreter) with the INNER JOIN worked fine tho when referencing Fellows.User_ID, which was apparently not the case in the ORM.

Although it is working, my sql relational might be wrong or not ideal, therefore I am still open to suggestions!

Comment: Constraints need not hold or be declared or be known to query in SQL. (But if they hold then some expressions return the same as others you could have used anyway, that otherwise wouldn't.) An ORM uses FKs to let you write certain OO code that it maps to SQL; it might generate queries that are only correct if the FKs hold, but it needn't. (Or that might require less processing, but the DBMS uses constraints to minimize computation for SQL code anyway.) Exercise: Learn what tables ORM declarations create & compare query OO code to the simplest equivalent SQL not relying on constraints.

Comment: The reason constraints aren't needed to query is that in the relational model every query expression & its table value denotes a relation(ship)/association & the rows satisfying it; a query builds a relation(ship)/association & its rows from base table relation(ship)s/associations & rows. FKs are ubiquitously wrongly called "relationships" by misrepresentations of the relational & ER models; they & other constraints are always-true statements the DBMS uses to disallow invalid updates (& optimize). (ORMs are unnecessary & restrictive & just offer a pointer-oriented access to an obscured DB.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and explanations!
That's a looot of information, I will take time this week to learn deeper on how it works and avoid such situation in the future, have a nice day!! :)